# CKEditorの画像アップロード先を変更したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

現在、railsでCkeditorにcarrierwaveを使って、画像アップロード機能を作成していますが、
/blog/以下にサービスを構築をしているためPathが合わずエラーが起こります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記URLを以下に変更した場合
http://localhost:3000/blog/ckeditor/pictures?&CKEditor=post_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=ja
だとアクセス出来るという状況です。

そこで画像アップロードのパスを/blog/以下に変更したいのですが、どのように行えば良いかわかりますでしょうか。
CKEDITOR_BASEPATHというのを変えて見ましたが、うまくいかず、、、

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl　これは設定ファイルについてのドキュメントです。config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/blog/ckeditor/pictures';　を設定してみてください。

Comment: basepath.js.erbのファイルにCKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/blog/ckeditor/pictures'
});を追加してみましたが変わらないですね

Comment: なぜbasepath.js.erbに追加したんでしょうか.erbファイルはCKEditorブラウザ側で初期化されるときに、実行されるのでしょうか？ブラウザのほうデバッグして、試したほうが良さそうですね。